# Replace header placeholder, not working now

Tags: c#, openxml

I want to replace the placeholder 'plcDate' in the header of the doc. Headers start from 2nd page in my doc template.

I'm using the below code. But 'headDate' is always null.

Don't know whether I've to change the code or the doc template.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(NewPath, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    foreach (HeaderPart hpart in mainPart.HeaderParts)
    {
        SdtElement headDate = hpart.Header.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "plcDate").SingleOrDefault();
        if (headDate != null)
        {
            headDate.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(new Run(new Text(dateValue))));
        }
    }
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Comment: In the `foreach` is it a typo that once you have `headDate` and twice `headSDate`?

Comment: Sorry. It's a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Worked after using the following code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(NewPath, true))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                    string content = null;

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(theDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.First().GetStream()))
                    {
                        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    Regex exheadDate = new Regex("plcDate");
                    content = exheadDate.Replace(content, "27/07/1992");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(theDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.First().GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        writer.Write(content);
                    }
                    mainPart.Document.Save();
                }
```